# Nvidia Card not detected -- clean install -- Have tried many solutions

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I have a Dell L501x with a clean install (now clean, anyway) of 12.04.

My issue is that I do not have anything in the additional/restricted driver dialog. I have an Optimus Nvidia 425m I believe with the associated Intel card.

Now, from a fresh install (since I've already failed at attempting to use xorg-edger ppa, using ironhide, bumblebee, etc) how would I set up my Nvidia card so that I can at the very least, have it show up as a named card and not as "unknown". My eventual goal is to play Minecraft with decent framerates.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed [these](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) instructions and still couldn't get your nvidia card to work?